# How to make the data values ​in vue v-simple-table add up to average?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-simple-table.

The value of "TotalAverage" is the total average of "ggFinalgrade".

What can I do to get this value?

[Current picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7a2Q4.png)

[The picture I want to present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJGo.png)

The first value is 20

because (30+20+10)/3=20

The second value is 25

because (30+20)/2=25

My code

```
<template><div><v-card tile>
  <v-card-title>{{ fixed.CardTitle }}</v-card-title>
  <v-simple-table><thead><tr>
        <th class="text-left" width="25%">{{ fixed.CourseSectionsName }}</th>
        <th class="text-left" width="35%">{{ fixed.GradeItemsItemname }}</th>
        <th class="text-center" width="10%">{{ fixed.QuizAttemptsTimefinish }}</th>
        <th class="text-center" width="10%">{{ fixed.QuestionAttemptsResponsesummary }}</th>
        <th class="text-center" width="10%">{{ fixed.GradeGradesFinalgrade }}</th>
        <th class="text-center" width="10%">{{ fixed.TotalAverage }}</th>
      </tr></thead><tbody>
      <tr v-for="grade in grades" :key="grade.name">
        <td class="text-left ">
          {{ grade.csName }}</td>
        <td class="text-lefe">
          <div class="my-3" v-for="group in grade.group" :key="group.name">
            <a :href="group.url" style="text-decoration:none">
              {{ group.giItemname }}</a></div></td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div class="my-3" v-for="qzaTimefinish in grade.qzaTimefinish" :key="qzaTimefinish.name">
            {{ qzaTimefinish }}</div></td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div class="my-3" v-for="qaResponsesummary in grade.qaResponsesummary" :key="qaResponsesummary.name">
            {{ qaResponsesummary }}</div></td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div class="my-3 text-center" v-for="group in grade.group" :key="group.name">
            {{ group.ggFinalgrade }}</div></td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ TotalAverage }}</td>
        </tr></tbody>
</v-simple-table></v-card></div></template>
<script>
export default { data() { return {
  fixed: {
    CardTitle: "課程1",
    CourseSectionsName: "內容",
    GradeItemsItemname: "測驗卷",
    QuizAttemptsTimefinish: "日期",
    QuestionAttemptsResponsesummary: "教師",
    GradeGradesFinalgrade: "結果",
    TotalAverage: "總平均"
  },
  grades: [
    {
      csName: "內容1",
      group: [{
          giItemname: "測驗1-1",url: "",ggFinalgrade: 30},
        {
          giItemname: "測驗1-2",url: "",ggFinalgrade: 20},
        {
          giItemname: "測驗1-3",url: "",ggFinalgrade: 10}],
      qzaTimefinish: ["0913", "0913", "1415"],
      qaResponsesummary: ["教師1", "教師3", "教師4"]},
    {
      csName: "內容2",
      group: [{
          giItemname: "測驗2-1",url: "",ggFinalgrade: 30},
        {
          giItemname: "測驗2-2",url: "",ggFinalgrade: 20}],
      qzaTimefinish: ["0913", "1415"],
      qaResponsesummary: ["教師1", "教師2"]
    }]};}};</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i. first add method,

ii. then calculate the average and return.

iii. finally print the totalAverage.

```
totalAverage(grades) {
   var average = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
       average+= Number(grades[i].ggFinalgrade);
   }
   return average / grades.length;    
},
```

replace `{{TotalAverage }}` with `{{ totalAverage( grade.group) }}`

Comment: I modified and added the following two points, but my picture has not changed
1.<td class="text-center">{{ totalAverage(grade.group) }}</td>
2.mounted: {
    totalAverage(grades) {
      var average = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        average += Number(grades[i].ggFinalgrade);
      }
      return average;
    }
  }

Comment: And the card disappears without being displayed

Comment: then, there must be some error. can you debug?

check the `grades value` on `totalAverage function`, the grades is an array or not?

Comment: yeah, you didnt put totalAverage function on methods.

Comment: change this one `}};</script>` to, 
`}, methods:{  //here put the answered function.   }};`

Comment: Success! Thank you very much